# How to play audio clip in Windows Store XAML/C# application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to figure out how I can play an MP3 file that is bundled as part of my application, i.e I don't want to use the file picker to select the file I want to play, the file will be in my project. So every time I press a button I want the file to play automatically, I don't need any play/pause/stop controls, how do i achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't [WMPLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx) work? You can specify the URL for the player without user interaction.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work in a metro app, anyway i figured it out will post the solution bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it like this. Added the wav into my project, dragged a MediaElement control onto my XAML page.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="playSound" Source="Assets/mysound.wav" AutoPlay="False" Height="0" Width="0"  />
```

Then in the code behind on the event handler that I want to play on

```
playSound.Play();
```